# PHP array ignore duplicate values

Tags: php

What would  be the best way to ignore the duplicates for customer_name in this grouped array? I only want to display a list of unique names.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [model_id] => 1
                    [work_order] => 10999
                    [id] => 1
                    [model_name] => STC1.5
                    [stock] => 3
                    [free] => 1
                    [customer_name] => Jane Doe
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [model_id] => 1
                    [work_order] => 10998
                    [id] => 1
                    [model_name] => STC1.5
                    [stock] => 3
                    [free] => 1
                    [customer_name] => Jane Doe
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: have you tried array_unique()? this should work for you `array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Which record should be ignored, `10998` or `10999`?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you need to get only the list of `customer_name`s without duplicates or you need to remove some entries of the array to avoid having two entries with the same `customer_name`? If the latter case is the correct one then you should define the rules of ignoring the duplicates (apart from them having the same `customer_name`). What entry to keep when a duplicate is detected? The first one? The last one? The one that have the smallest/biggest value in `id`? etc.

Comment: I need to display a list of all customer names unless they are duplicated. It doesn't matter which is displayed as long as all the names are unique.

Comment: Would `Jane Doe` and a misspelled `jane Doe` be two people?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you **ONLY** care about unique names and `$arr` is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [model_id] => 1
                    [work_order] => 10999
                    [id] => 1
                    [model_name] => STC1.5
                    [stock] => 3
                    [free] => 1
                    [customer_name] => Jane Doe
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [model_id] => 1
                    [work_order] => 10998
                    [id] => 1
                    [model_name] => STC1.5
                    [stock] => 3
                    [free] => 1
                    [customer_name] => Jane Doe
                )

        )
)
```

then you can use:

```
$unique_names = array_keys(array_flip(array_column($arr[1],'customer_name')));
```

---

If you are concerned about micro-optimization then try:

```
$unique_names = array();

foreach( $arr[1] as $v )
{
    $unique_names[$v['customer_name']] = $v['customer_name'];
}
```

Comment: There are easier (and probably faster) ways to get the list of (unique) names.

Comment: @axiac Which part in specific is inefficient?

Comment: When I commented, the answer was using `array_map()` with a user function callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with only the name with array_column and use array_unique on that.
Then use array_intersect_key to get the corresponding subarrays from the main array.

```
$name = array_unique(array_column($arr[1], "customer_name"));
$unique = array_intersect_key($arr, $name);
```